# Migration states to make a column nullable but update-database generate sql with NOT NULL for this

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am using EF core with MVC. I just changed a column(of type int) from non nullable(int) to nullable(int?). The column was used as a foreign key.

like

```
 [Column("TRIPCHARGES")]
 [ForeignKey("TripCharges")]
 int? TripChargesId { get; set; }
```

and created the migration(using add-migration) as follows.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

namespace RailRoad.DataPersistenct.EFCore.Migrations
{
    public partial class MadeTripsRecordTripChargesIdnullable : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
                name: "FK_TRIPSRECORD_TRIPCHARGES_TRIPCHARGES",
                table: "TRIPSRECORD");

            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
                name: "TRIPCHARGES",
                table: "TRIPSRECORD",
                nullable: true,
                oldClrType: typeof(int),
                oldType: "int");

            migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
                name: "FK_TRIPSRECORD_TRIPCHARGES_TRIPCHARGES",
                table: "TRIPSRECORD",
                column: "TRIPCHARGES",
                principalTable: "TRIPCHARGES",
                principalColumn: "TRIPCHARGES_ID",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
                name: "FK_TRIPSRECORD_TRIPCHARGES_TRIPCHARGES",
                table: "TRIPSRECORD");

            migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
                name: "TRIPCHARGES",
                table: "TRIPSRECORD",
                type: "int",
                nullable: false,
                oldClrType: typeof(int),
                oldNullable: true);

            migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
                name: "FK_TRIPSRECORD_TRIPCHARGES_TRIPCHARGES",
                table: "TRIPSRECORD",
                column: "TRIPCHARGES",
                principalTable: "TRIPCHARGES",
                principalColumn: "TRIPCHARGES_ID",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I ran the command `update-database -v`

I saw the following sql got executed:

```
Executing DbCommand [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
ALTER TABLE TRIPSRECORD MODIFY `TRIPCHARGES` int NOT NULL;
Executed DbCommand (1,209ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
ALTER TABLE TRIPSRECORD MODIFY `TRIPCHARGES` int NOT NULL;
Creating DbCommand for 'ExecuteNonQuery'.
```

Also I checked the database column definition for the table and the column was still having the not null constraint.

I don't know what is wrong here, please help.
Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Seeing the same in reverse, trying to make it not null instead of nullable.